# VS Code Tslint library failed to load

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I start VS Code the tslint library gives me this error

> Failed to load tslint library. Please install tslint in your workspace

I have reinstalled it and but again it gives me the same error.

The current version of tslint I'm using is `0.5.24`

I have tried by enabling tslint globally so it should be available to all workspaces followed by [Microsoft vscode tslint issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tslint/issues/3) but it also doesn't help me.

I enabled `"tslint.enable": true,` in vscode workspace settings. but again I have got same results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install globally with npm:

```
npm install typescript -g
npm install tslint -g
```

Switch to the root of your TypeScript project and generate a starting tslint.jsonconfig file:

```
cd path/to/my/project
tslint --init
```

Lint your TypeScript files!

```
tslint -c path/to/tslint.json path/to/typescript/file.ts
```

Checkout full [usage guide](http://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/cli/) for more.